# WTForms form displays invalid when using the back button

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am building a Flask app and I use WTF forms.

My main page uses the MainForm which has a select field to choose a 'Tenant', two date fields and one Submit button which redirects to another page. The MainForm looks like:

```
class MainForm(Form):
    tenant = SelectField('Tenant', choices=get_tenants())
    start_date = DateField('From',
                       [validators.DataRequired('Please enter a valid date'),
                        DateRange(min=datetime(2013, 04, 01).date(), max=datetime.now().date())],
                       format='%Y-%m-%d', default=datetime.now().date())
    end_date = DateField('To',
                     [validators.DataRequired('Please enter a valid date'),
                      DateRange(min=datetime(2013, 04, 01).date(), max=datetime.now().date())],
                     format='%Y-%m-%d', default=datetime.now().date())
    room_stats = SubmitField('Room Stats')
```

In the new page `/room-stats` there is another form which has only one 'Back' button which redirects to the main page. It looks like:

```
class StatsForm(Form):
    back = SubmitField('Back')
```

The view functions look like:

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def index():
    form = MainForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['start_date'] = str(form.start_date.data)
        session['end_date'] = str(form.end_date.data)

        if current_user.is_administrator():
            session['username'] = str(form.tenant.data)
        else:
            session['username'] = str(current_user.username)

        if form.room_stats.data:
            return redirect(url_for('main.room_stats'))

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

and

```
@main.route('/room-stats')
@login_required
def room_stats():
    form = StatsForm()

    [MORE_CODE_HERE]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.back.data:
            return redirect(url_for(index))

    return render_template('stats/room_stats.html', form=form)
```

Finally, the `room_stats.html` file has a form like:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</form>
```

The app generally works fine but there is a problem about validation. Every time I click the `Back`  button and I go back to my main form the `Tenant` field is highlighted in red and there a message

> Not a valid choice

even though the field has a value and it is not blank.

I assume something is going wrong with the validation, but I cannot figure out what. 
It is also strange that the `Tenant` field has no validators, so why is there this error message?

Comment: Try to skip validation on GET: `if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():`.  The `request` object must be imported from Flask if it isn't already.

Comment: You should try to reduce the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem before asking a question here. E.g. you could remove irrelevant form fields.